# Xcode iOS Templating

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am creating an iOS 8 app with Swift in Xcode 6.1.x. I am customizing the look of the app so it doesn't have the generic iOS 8 feel.

Is there some way within Xcode to create some sort of templating or theming system so that every time I add in a new view, and I can base it off some sort of template? I am looking to change things like the header style, background, fonts, etc... A feature such as this should prevent me from having to re-theme every time I create a new view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many objects conform to the [`UIAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html) protocol, which you can use to preconfigure various properties for controls.

> I am looking to change things like the header style, background, fonts, etc...

I assume by the header you mean the navigation bar?  The bar tint color, background image, and title text attributes are all marked as UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR in the header, so they should all be configurable via the appearance proxy.  For example:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
```

Comment: Excellent! This should get me going in the right direction. Thank you.